# Laravel Rule Validation Check Databse Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, validation

this is my code:

```
  $id_project = $request->id;
  $rfid       = $request->rfid;

  $validateData = $request->validate([
                    'name'      => 'required|string|max:255',
                    'rfid'      => 'required|min:40',[
                                    Rule::exists('usersdata')->where(function($query) use ($id_project,$rfid){
                                       $query->where('id_project', $id_project)->where('rfid', $rfid);
                                    }),
                    ],
                    'description'   => 'string|max:255|nullable',
                ]);

   $user = UserModel::create($validateData);
   return Response()->json(['success' => 'success insert data'], 200);
```

Validation for RFID (*required or Min 40 char*) its working.
but if i'm insert with same id_project and same RFID data that's not working. 
whereas in my database have already have id_project and rfid. 
keep successful inserting data.

Comment: Shouldn't be `Rule::unique`?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte i do with `unique` that give same results, success inserting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax fault on your code, compare your code with this corrected one:

```php
$validateData = $request->validate([
    'name'      => 'required|string|max:255',
    'rfid'      => [
                       'required',
                       'min:40',
                       Rule::unique('usersdata', 'rfid')
                           ->where('id_project', $id_project)
                   ],
    'description'   => 'string|max:255|nullable',
]);
```